# A raster clipping script does not produce output

Tags: python, gdal, fiona

I am using the following code to first divide a vector layer to many polygons and after that use them for clipping parts of a raster layer. It successfully split the vector layer to many polygons, but it does not produce the raster clips. How can I make this code run?

```
import glob
import gdal
import fiona

with fiona.open('E:/data/vector.shp', 'r') as dst_in:
    for index, feature in enumerate(dst_in):
        with fiona.open('E:/data/polygons/NO_{}.shp'.format(index), 'w', **dst_in.meta) as dst_out:
            dst_out.write(feature)

shapefiles = glob.glob('E:/data/polygons/*.shp')
```

This part of the code produce no results and error:

```
for shapefile in shapefiles:
    features = fiona.open(shapefile, 'r')
    for feat in features:
    name = feat['properties']['Name']  
    command = 'gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -cutline {} ' \
              '-crop_to_cutline -of GTiff E:/data/raster.tif E:/data/outputraster/NO_{}.tif'.format(shapefile,name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following line under 'command' in your script:

```py
    Popen(command, shell=True)
```